# Get last 6 months monthname.month number and Years in simple select statement

Tags: sql-server, date

How to get last 6 months month name, month number and Years in simple select statement  in sqlserver .
**The no of months is 6, and is fixed**

```
12  Dec 2015
11  Nov 2015
10  Oct 2015
9   Sep 2015
8   Aug 2015
7   Jul 2015
6   Jun 2015
```

This should handle year end boundaries

say, if the current month is Feb 2016, the result should give 2015 months.

```
2   Feb 2016
1   Jan 2016
12  Dec 2015
11  Nov 2015
10  Oct 2015
9   Sep 2015
8   Aug 2015
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with the following:

```
SELECT  MONTH(DATEADD(mm, -m, GETDATE())) AS m,
        LEFT(DATENAME(mm,  DATEADD(mm, -m, GETDATE())), 3) AS n,
        YEAR(DATEADD(mm, -m, GETDATE())) AS y
FROM    (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) t(m)
```

Output:

```
m   n   y
12  Dec 2015
11  Nov 2015
10  Oct 2015
9   Sep 2015
8   Aug 2015
7   Jul 2015
6   Jun 2015
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
;with cte as
(
select 0 as num
union all
select num+1 from cte where num<6
)
select month(dates),datename(month,dates),year(dates)
from 
(
select dateadd(mm,-num,datadd(dd,1,eomonth(getdate(),-1))) as dates
from cte
) A
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4681)

Answer (score 2):

```
select datepart(m,GETDATE()) MonthNumber,left(datename(month,GETDATE()),3) as Month,year(GETDATE()) as Year union all
select datepart(m,DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())) MonthNumber,left(datename(month,DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())),3) as Month,year(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())) as Year union all
select datepart(m,DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())) MonthNumber,left(datename(month,DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())),3) as Month,year(DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())) as Year union all
select datepart(m,DATEADD(month,-3,GETDATE())) MonthNumber,left(datename(month,DATEADD(month,-3,GETDATE())),3) as Month,year(DATEADD(month,-3,GETDATE())) as Year union all
select datepart(m,DATEADD(month,-4,GETDATE())) MonthNumber,left(datename(month,DATEADD(month,-4,GETDATE())),3) as Month,year(DATEADD(month,-4,GETDATE())) as Year union all
select datepart(m,DATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE())) MonthNumber,left(datename(month,DATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE())),3) as Month,year(DATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE())) as Year union all
select datepart(m,DATEADD(month,-6,GETDATE())) MonthNumber,left(datename(month,DATEADD(month,-6,GETDATE())),3) as Month,year(DATEADD(month,-6,GETDATE())) as Year
```

The above query will work for most of the RDBMS.
For SQL Server specific use the below query.

```
SELECT  MONTH(DATEADD(month, -month, GETDATE())) AS MonthNumber ,
        LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,  DATEADD(month, -month, GETDATE())), 3) AS MonthName,
        YEAR(DATEADD(month, -month, GETDATE())) AS Year
FROM    ( VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5),(6) ) t ( month )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try DATEADD:

```
Select * FROM Table where YourDate>=DATEADD(m, -6, GETDATE())
```